# Подсчитать колличество в таблице из 2х имеющихся таблиц и записать обратно

Tags: sql, sql-server

Обращаемся к таблице post,
проверяем item_count > 0,
получаем post_id,
с помощью полученного post_id формируем запрос в таблицу post_item_admin на количество строк в таблице по данному post_id из таблицы post,
дальше формируем запрос на инсерт
UPDATE INTO post(post_id, item_count) где item_count = количеству post_id из таблицы post_item_admin.

Мои попытки

```
UPDATE INTO post(t2.post_id, count(t2.post_id))
SELECT
  t1.post_id,
  t1.item_count
FROM
  post t1,
  post_item_admin t2
WHERE
  t1.item_count > 0 and
  t2.post_id = t1.post_id

UPDATE INTO post(t2.post_id, count(t2.post_id))
SELECT
  t1.post_id,
  t1.item_count
FROM
  post t1,
  post_item_admin t2
WHERE
  t1.item_count > 0 and
  t2.post_id = t1.post_id
count(t2.post_id)
```

Comment: Обычный многотабличный UPDATE. В качестве источника - группирующий подзапрос.

Comment: *формируем запрос на инсерт UPDATE INTO post* Ты б определился, инсерт или апдейт... *Мои попытки* Попытка придумать UPDATE INTO - несомненно, зачётная. Но у сервера есть свой синтаксис, и чужого ему не нужно.